# Hibernate version as composite primary key

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I was able to use id and version columns as composite primary key in GORM. The problem is that now the version is not automatically updated and is now fixed at 0 and If I try to change it manually it gives my Row updated exception. Is there a way to use version as part of composite primary key and still let hibernate handle it as auto increment?

Here is my mapping:

```
static mapping = {
        id composite:['id', 'version']
        version insertable: false, updateable: false
    }
```

and here how I handle increment of id:

```
def beforeInsert() {
        if (id == null) {
            def max=Reservation.createCriteria().get {
                projections { max "id" }
            } as Long
            id = max+1
        }
    }
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why? Given that id will be unique, why isn't it enough?

Comment: I want to keep history of each change for the given id.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better keeping the history as part of an audit table?

Comment: We want both of them.

Comment: You shouldn't change the PK of your data, if you want that you should create a new object every time you update with that new version number. I think you can do it but not with the hibernate version column, you should implement your own.